# Updating database

Tags: integration, leads

Our company are about the implement a Salesforce CRM but there are some outstanding technical questions regarding the process of updating the database.

Our website has a database of our users and their details, at the same time the Salesforce CRM will have a database with relevant current members and new leads.

If the details of one of the users is updated on the website database is there an easy way to update it on the Salesforce CRM database? Ideally we don't want to be manually updating details on a daily basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which Salesforce licences do you have ? Professional ? Enterprise ? Unlimited ?

Salesforce grants you access to standard API. It allows you to access (read, create, edit, delete) every object in your organization (standard and custom objects). 
Thanks to that API, you can develop a webservice to update Salesforce from any third-party system.
I guess you'll also need to develop a webservice from Salesforce to your third-party system if you want both environment to be up-to-date.

If you need more details about that API :
SOAP API : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm
REST API : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm

Comment: Hi Mickael, we have not decided on the licenses yet. The API will certainly do the job, we may be using the customer community cloud which will tie into our current website and ensure there is a smooth communication between the CRM and member login area. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can surely Update the salesforce CRM database once  one of the users data is updated on the website database . Please make use of one ETL tools which can automate this process . You can get some links on appexchange

Comment: Are you affiliated with this product?

Comment: Full disclosure: Raghu is affiliated with the first link posted, but not the second.

Comment: I have used those products in order to achieve some integrations .